# patch value issue when update the form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

when updating the form I am using the patch value to show the  created data in the form, iam able to show the created data in all form fields but except one field.i used the setValue also to show the data of that particular field,but its not working, can anyone provide a solution.
this is the code 
ts

```php
 public addMaterialForm = this.fb.group({

    barcodes:[],
    labelSpecs:[],
    labelSize: [''],

  })

 ngOnInit() { 
    this.receiptSrv.currentSharedMaterial.distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.addMaterialForm.patchValue(data);
        this.editMode =true;
      }
    });
  }
```

html

```html
<!-- Label Size -->
<div fxLayout="row">
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Barcodes Size</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="labelSize" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let barcode of barcodes" [value]="barcode">
        Barcodes Size- {{barcode.height}} X {{barcode.width}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngFor="let labelSizeMsg of materialInfoValMsg.labelSize">
        <mat-error class="error-message" *ngIf="addMaterialForm.get('labelSize').hasError(labelSizeMsg.type) &&
            (addMaterialForm.get('labelSize').dirty || addMaterialForm.get('labelSize').touched)">
        {{labelSizeMsg.message}}
        </mat-error>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

This is the response coming from the backend

```
labelSize: "{"createdAt":null,"modifiedAt":null,"createdBy":null,"modifiedBy":null,"id":"641a55d1-1026-4093-b339-02174b09891a","height":1,"width":1}"
```

I need to show the width and height in the barcodeSize field of the form like this BarcodeSize-1X1.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this documentation [angular-reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) I saw de the following

> the patchValue() method applies the update against the model structure. PatchValue() only updates properties that the form model defines.

So, your addMaterialForm  is an object with this structure 

 `{
    barcodes: null,
    labelSpecs: null,
    labelSize: null
 }`

And you're trying to update it with a objet with this strucutre

`{
  "createdAt": null,
  "modifiedAt": null,
  "createdBy": null,
  "modifiedBy": null,
  "id": "641a55d1-1026-4093-b339-02174b09891a",
  "height": 1,
  "width": 1
}`

It won't work since it doesn't know which propertie of your form it should set.

Your API should return something like this:

`{
 "labelSize": {
    "createdAt": null,
    "modifiedAt": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "id": "641a55d1-1026-4093-b339-02174b09891a",
    "height": 1,
    "width": 1
  }
}`